# Issue with using regular expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to run the following bit of code in python.

```
import re
text = 'Hello 16 Hello 22 Hello 81 Hello 50'
sum = 0
for m in re.finditer('Hello', text):
  print('found', m.start(), m.end())
  a = m.end()
  b = m.end()+3
  print (text[a:b])
  block = str(text[a:b])
  sum += block
  print (sum)
```

I am continually getting this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

All I want to do is have my code parse through the text and add together specified numbers contained in it.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: you need to `cast` the matched block into an int before summing.

Comment: Replace with sum = sum +int( block)

Comment: @user1929959 how will that help?! Augmented assignment is (generally) the same as the standard equivalent; `sum = sum + block` will have exactly the same error as `sum += block`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add an `str` to an `int` in `sum += block`. You should convert `block` first to `int`. Change line:

```
 block = str(text[a:b])
```

to:

```
 block = int(text[a:b])
```

Comment: Thanks! Changing to int fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your sum is an `int` and you are trying to add a `str` to it. I think you mean

```
  block = int(text[a:b])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've understood something wrong but to find some numbers in a string you can just use `r'\d+'`.
This code will sum all numbers in a string:

```
sum(int(i) for i  in re.findall(r'\d+', 'Hello, 7, 89 Vlad'))
```